# Insert a row when you have a foreign key

Tags: mysql, django

I have the following model

```
class Hostel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name ', 'room_number'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HOSTELS)
    room_number= models.IntegerField()
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=FACULTIES, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.faculty + ': ' + self.name + ' - ' + str(self.room_number)


class MultimeStabila(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Hostel, primary_key=True)
    guest1= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    guest2= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    guest3= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="")
    guest4= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="")
    guest5= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.guest1+ ' - ' + self.guest2+ ' - ' + self.guest3+ ' - ' + self.guest4 + ' - ' + self.guest5
```

Now I want to do an insert in MultimeStabila table a,b,c,d,e guests in room number 14

```
 c = conn.cursor()
 c.execute("SELECT * from stable_hostel where room_number = %s", [14])
 data = c.fetchall()
 c.execute("INSERT INTO stable_multimestabila(hostel_id, guest1, guest2, guest3, guest4, guest5) VALUES(%s, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')", [data[0]])
 conn.commit()
```

but it tells me

```
(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance

P.S.: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950124/how-to-insert-into-a-foreignkey-field-using-raw-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post which seems to fit my problem, but it does not work.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why yo use raw queries and not Django's ORM?

Comment: The main reason is that I did not work so far with any ORM and I find it easier in this way.

Comment: @Siviu: well this actually will cancel most of the benefit of Django. If you later migrate your model, it is possible you need to rewrite all of the queries.

Comment: I will try from now to use ORM, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem with the query

I think you have to analyze the type first. You write a query like:

```
SELECT * from stable_hostel where room_number = 14
```

And you perform a `fetchall` on that. As a result, you will get a collection of rows. And every row is a collection of cells.

Now in case you use `[data[0]]` so that means you constructed a *list* with an *entire* row, whereas the next SQL statement only expects *one* value: an `id`. We can fix this with:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT id from stable_hostel where room_number = %s", [14])
data = c.fetchall()
c.execute("INSERT INTO stable_multimestabila(hostel_id, guest1, guest2, guest3, guest4, guest5) VALUES(%s, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')", [data[0][0]])
conn.commit()
```

So we only fetch the `id`, and we only use the first cell. But this is still not very elegant as well as inefficient: what if there are multiple hostels with the same room number? Or none? You need to take those into consideration as well.

## Using Django's ORM

We can write it with Django's ORM as well, as:

```
hostel = Hostel.objects.get(room_number=14)
MultimeStabila.objects.create(
    room=hostel,
    guest1='a',
    guest2='b',
    guest3='c',
    guest4='d',
    guest5='e'
)
```

This is usually more readable, more declarative, in case your model (slightly) changes, then you will usually not have to rewrite the queries. Note that you still need to resolve the case where the hostel with that number dos not exists, or there are multiple ones.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it was very helpful!